# Jenkins run that executes a simple shell script on multiple amazon instances

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to find an ideal solution which will help me execute a simple shell script that deletes files in order to clean up the space on several amazon instances on a regular basis.

I have looked into Configuration Matrix and from what I can tell by reading up on it is that I will have to define slaves on which I can execute the script.

I am unable to find a simple tutorial that targets this problem. I am hoping that someone can give an example or share a reference regarding this.

If you know of any other alternative then please do share that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest to use Ansible. Setup your ssh-key infrastructure that you can access all instances from your jenkins server. Try to delete files that way one by one. Then setup a jenkins job where you can choose your targets (and maybe also the files) and pass the selected values to ansible.

Comment: I don't think that will be possible for me at this stage, as for the slave idea I am starting to think that it is not the right way to go about this. I am currently looking into https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh-credentials plugin to help ease the process.